# `How to Converting a ASCII array to text in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, converters

I receive a telegram from the network which is an array of bytes for example:

```
 [0]    0x34    
 [1]    0x35    
 [2]    0x35    
 [3]    0x37
```

0x34 is the hex value of the char 4 and 0x35 is the hex value of the char 5 in the ASCII table and so on

I can convert this to a string with

```
 string s = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString(Tel, 0, Tel.Length);
```

which results in

```
4557
```

Now I have to convert this into 0x45 and 0x57 because 0x45 is the value of the char 'E' and 0x57 is the 'W'

Is there any way to convert 4557 into the string EW in C#? I know it's a bit strange protocol but I have no idea how to convert the received telegram to get a 'EW' vom the array above.

For sending something I could use

```
ToCharArray()
```

but I have no idea how to convert the received telegram

I hope you understand my problem

Comment: Do you have an official specification of the 'telegram' format that we can see?

Comment: @MarkusSafar I dont think this is duplicate question. Parts of the question needs Hex to char conversion, however it also contains string splitting.

Comment: Since you know how to convert the bytes to a string, why spend half the question on that part? Instead, focus on converting the string `"4557"` into the two bytes (characters?) `0x45` and `0x57`, equivalent to `"EW"`.

Comment: Requirements like these make my spider-sense tingle. Your “array of bytes” is a plain ordinary ASCII string; why are you reading them as bytes? Why do you think they are UTF8? You need a specification or a significantly larger example.

Comment: I agree this is not a duplicate it is a two part question. 1: Convert from hex to char, 2: Convert from int to hex to char.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

How about doing it all in a single loop so that you don't have to convert the string representation. This contains no error handling...

```
var bytes = new byte[] { 0x34, 0x35, 0x35, 0x37 };
var output = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i += 2)
{
    output.Append(Char.ConvertFromUtf32(
       Convert.ToInt32(
           ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString(
               new byte[] { bytes[i], bytes[i + 1] }, 0, 2), 16)));
}
```

ouput = "EW"

Comment: Why you showing example of converting bytes to UTF8 string when OP clearly stated that input is ASCII? (The fact OP provided some broken code should not mean you need to copy-paste it in the answer).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - hmmmm do you see ASCIIEnconding? Did you bother trying my code? Maybe you should before you comment.

Comment: I did read your code, there is no need to run it to know what is doing. Did you see [Encoding.UTF8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.utf8?view=netframework-4.7.2) call in the code you've posted?

Comment: Thank you this solved my problem. :-) Sorry for the long text above but I didn' know if you would understand what my problem is without the explaining.

Comment: @Fellnase - I'm glad it solved your problem. If you found it helpul please accept the asnwer as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the extension method

```
public static IEnumerable<byte> HexToByte(this string s, int partLength)
{
    if (s == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("s");
    if (partLength <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("Part length has to be positive.", "partLength");

    for (var i = 0; i < s.Length; i += partLength)
        yield return Convert.ToByte(s.Substring(i, Math.Min(partLength, s.Length - i)), 16);
}
```

and the below command uses extension method to convert string to byte and print as char

```
input.HexToByte(2).ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine((char)x));
```